# Find new coordinates after using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation on an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, cgaffinetransform

This is a simple issue, which is bugging me ...

So, I have an object of `UIImageView` over which, I use

```
-(void)rotate {

// ...

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180));
self.image.transform = transform; // image is a property.

}
```

So, when I call this method once, it rotates the object !. When I call the method again, I expect the object to be rotated again - but it is not rotating by another 180 degrees. After messing with the coordinates and moving the image, I can understand that the `-perspective` of the object has also be rotated by 180 degrees and all coordinates have been inverted as well.

I want the object's perspective to be restored (although it's been rotated by some angle) such that, I can continue to rotate and move it just like before !

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried self.image.transform += transform; ?

Comment: @Eugene, have **you** tried to += two CGAffineTransforms?

Comment: Yeah, right. Sorry, I remembered I've added the values inside the function of CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. Disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with `CABasicAnimation` !

Comment: You can use the CGAffineTransformRotate which has two parameters:    self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.image.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180));

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, this code works:

```
UIImage* rotateUIImage(const UIImage* src, float angleDegrees)  {   
  UIView* rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, src.size.width, src.size.height)];
  float angleRadians = angleDegrees * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);
  CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians);
  rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
  CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
  CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);
  CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, angleRadians);

  CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
  CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-src.size.width / 2, -src.size.height / 2, src.size.width, src.size.height), [src CGImage]);

  UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return newImage;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure, I just found this code in the internet, tested it out in my app, rotations were being made just as expected, so I decided to share what I've found. You can just disregard the code if you need complex explanations, because I can hardly provide them. :\